# Wolfram notebook Dynamic not updating in wolfram cloud

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, wolfram-cloud

I have this very simple program:

```
n=0;
{
Button["Play", a = RandomInteger[10];b = RandomInteger[10];n+=1 ],
Dynamic[a], "vs", Dynamic[b], "draw number:", Dynamic[n]
}
```

When I run it, only the first variable visually updates in the output line. If I ask for the value of b or n, I can see that they do change every time, but it is not dynamically visible. This is a big problem for me. Is it ab browser issue? Sometimes the b gets updated, sometimes not...

[image: what it looks like when I run it]

Comment: I see both a and b update, so I don't know what trouble you're having with b. But n was never given a value, so n+=1 can't actually have an effect. You need to initialize n to some value .

Comment: sorry yes. in my notebook I sent n=0 before I run this. Could it be like a browser issue? is there a recommended browser to run Wolfram-cloud?

Comment: I tried switching a and b in the dynamic at the Bottom, and still only a gets updated when I click the button.

Comment: Indeed. I just tried in in wolframcloud (using Safari), and I see the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @lericr this is almost a relief, I'm not going nuts :)
Would you mind telling me how you got it to run as expected? Browser and OS?

Comment: When I ran it locally in a Mathematica notebook (so, not in the cloud), your code worked as expected with all three dynamics updating properly. When I ran it in the cloud (wolframcloud.com), the only Dynamic that seemed to be working was the first one. I could swap out the variables, but only the first Dynamic updated dynamically (so, whichever variable was in ther first Dynamic was the one whose updates were captured).

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with CompoundExpression in a Button. Or maybe it has something to do with multiple Dynamics in a single output cell in wolframcloud. IDK, I haven't experimented.

Comment: UPDATE: I also tried the following code. Weirdly enough, o gets updated with an updated version of a, but the rest is static. This is some serious bug. How could they have no noticed that, and/or just leave it like this? It makes cloud coding possibilities very limited. 
`n=0;
{Button["Play", a = RandomInteger[100];b = RandomInteger[100];n+=1 ]}
o = {Dynamic[a], "vs",Dynamic@b, "Draw number:",Dynamic@n};
Dynamic[o]`

Comment: Hello user3447795, I think it would make sense to mention in the question or even the title that you encounter this problem in the cloud only. That will avoid a lot of people trying this and not seeing the problem. I think the majority of readers here will typically still use the desktop version...

Comment: I just have tried this with both chrome and firefox on windows: neither do work correctly. I think this looks like a bug in the cloud version (only). You might want to report this to WRI. But I am not entirely sure whether they consider Dynamic already a supported feature in the cloud. I think at least a few years ago it was not...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be a "limitation" of the cloud version... although it sometime actually work for a short moment.
I did, however, find a work around:

```
n=0;
{
Button["Play", a = RandomInteger[10];b = RandomInteger[10];n+=1 ],
Dynamic[a], "vs", Dynamic[b+a-a], "draw number:", Dynamic[n+a-a]
}
```

The first variable that gets dynamically computer refresh, so if we use it in the other Dynamic[] functions, they refresh "as expected"...